# Android Studio Dolphin: Failed to initialize editor

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

After updating android studio I can't open editor section. (Android Studio Dolphin)

**I tried**

- Invalidate caches and restart.
- Deleted the /.gradle & /.idea files

---

[image]

Comment: Update you gradle lastest one or fresh install Dolphin version android studio.